# Getting Ubuntu 23.04 to run XRDP on Hyper-V (Windows 11)

Tags: display-resolution, xfce, xrdp, hyper-v

I'd like to be able to run my 23.04 hyper-v image on full-screen.
I've tried a few options: I've installed xrdp, xfce4 and xorgxrdp I've used various setup scripts that have made changes to ~/.xsession and grub to no avail (like this one: https://c-nergy.be/blog/?p=18725 ) I've tried just upping the default screen resolution with some tools like xrandr and hit failures like; "Failed to get gamma size for default output". Firewall is disabled.
I'm essentially looking for something similar to this, but will work with 23.04.
https://github.com/microsoft/linux-vm-tools/tree/master/ubuntu/18.04

Microsoft doesn't even seem to have anything.